# How can I get the p-Value of the Durbin Watson Test in python?

Tags: python, statistics, p-value

I get the statistic value easily:

statsmodels.stats.stattools.durbin_watson(residuals, axis=0)

Any idea how I can get the p-value?
Thank you very much.

Comment: unfortunately no.. you cannot get it. see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136664/r-calculate-p-value-given-durbin-watson-statistic-and-n Most likely you have to use R or other softwares to get a p value..

Comment: Thank you, "Clever"Wolf ;-)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a table given n and k for critical values with alpha set to 1

https://www.real-statistics.com/statistics-tables/durbin-watson-table/

tables are too big to reproduce here.

Comment: I'm not sure how to add more context than the latest edit.  They're are multiple tables in jpg format.  I can't exactly include them in the post.

Comment: Well, usually short answers with just a link inside are signaled by bots in chat room. Seeing your answer I judged it a link only answer and agreed to the flag. Now, I understand that perhaps there is no better way to convoy this information. And about the downvote, sorry but it is not mine.